# Cancelling/Stopping Application.OnTime When I Cannot Access The Initial EarliestTime Variable

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code that I ran.

```
Option Explicit

Sub time()

Dim alertTime As Long

alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")

Application.OnTime alertTime, "Print"

End Sub
```

I have since ran

```
Application.OnTime alertTime, "Print",,Schedule:=False
```

But given that the time wont be same, I am afraid that the schedule is not canceling. Is their a way to cancel this through excels GUI? Unfortunately I do not know at what time I ran the macro. I suppose I could do a loop through the hour and cancel for every possible combination of seconds.

Comment: Your alertTime should be a double, not a long. A long will not include the time portion, only the date portion of Now or TimeValue.

Comment: @Jeeped ty. think that I will use Private Declare Function timeGetTime Lib "winmm.dll" () As Long and do something like if endTime - StartTime > 2000 to trigger my event. but appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: Declare `alertTime` as `Public` outside of the method, so it will remain the same and is available when you run with `Schedule:=False`. Should work without trouble as long as you don't stop all macro execution (and thus clear out your variables).
Stopping schedules through GUI is not possible as far as I know. You can just close the Application (!!!Not just the workbook!!!) and reopen it. Schedule is in the `Application` object scope, so that will erase / stop the tasks scheduled.